# My first CodeIgniter program: where should I write it?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ide

I just installed CodeIgniter, and it gave me the source code.

From what I understand, I should move the source code to my local server folder.

I did the configuration; but now what should I do next? What should I use to write code -- DreamWeaver, for example, like any other PHP file? Is there any GUI program dedicated for CodeIgniter?

Comment: codeigniter has good documentation i hear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first thing you should do is read the documentation. I do not use it myself, but I know for a matter of fact that CodeIgniter has some documentation. And there are heaps of introductions and getting started materials. (It also explains how and where to unpack it.)

- http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/watch/intro/
- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/getting_started.html
- http://www.google.com/search?q=codeigniter+introduction

Btw, there are no clicky-coloury apps that do the coding for you. You will have to resort to an editor; and yes Dreamweaver will do. And then learn the API.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter has excellent documentation, wiki and forum. For coding you can try Notepad++ (http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) which is free, light, colors syntax, have plugins,... and you can even put it on the usb.

After that you can try one of many IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

textmate has a bundle for CI, i do alot of CI development and I use the following

maamp for localhost
http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html

textmate for php html / css dev
http://macromates.com/

navicat for mysql managment
http://navicat.com/